# ObservableCollection not showing up in editor

Tags: unity, editors

I'm trying to use an `ObservableCollection` in a ScriptableObject, but it doesn't generate any serialized field in the asset editor.

Here is my code:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Dictionnary.Asset", menuName = "dictionnary")]
public class TADictionnary : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    public ObservableCollection<TAVerb> verbs;
}
```

```
[Serializable]
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Verb.Asset", menuName = "verb")]
public class TAVerb : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<string> synonyms;
    public string keyword;
}
```

I've read it used to not work on older unity version, but I'm using LTS 2022.3. So I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you read anything saying this *should* work in version 2022? I don't recall seeing serialization of ObservableCollections in any of the update notes in Unity's version log. [This related Q&A on StackOverflow shows how to implement your own version that serializes correctly for Inspector display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67578533). If you're using another source for your ObservableCollection, be sure to specify/link it in your question.

Comment: And is there a specific reason you need to use a `ObservableCollection` and not any of the other Collections available?

Comment: @DMGregory, I've seen that post, but I prefer to use native classes instead of implementing custom ones. But if I don't have any other options, I will implement that solution.